# 'Animator' does not contain a definition for 'StringToHash'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I programming a game for unity, and I downloaded from the asset store the 'Unity Samples: UI' package. But when I downloaded it it shows this error: `'Animator' does not contain a definition for 'StringToHash'`. The error is in the 'Panel Manager' file. Note that I'm using the newest version of Unity: 5.5.

The link for the 'Unity Samples: UI' package from the asset store: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/25468

Edit:
It doesn't allow me to click 'API Updater'.
[image]

Comment: I happens again with the same component 'Animator', but with the method 'SetBool', 'IsInTransition', `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo' and 'GetBool'

Comment: From Unity Console tab, Double click on the error. It will take you to where the problem is in the code. Tell us what the line of code that is causing the error looks like:

Comment: aimBool = Animator.StringToHash("Aim");

Comment: Above answer is from https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/28647 AimBehaviour.cs, line 19